# How to turn on error messages in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento 2 and it working.I just created the Hello world module and it working now.

My issue was I had called non existing method in execute method.

While trying to get it to work I tried to load the page it shows blank white screen, but no error.

How do I get errors to display in magento2?

Comment: What did you tried so far? Show your code! Please edit your question!

Comment: Enable developer mode using the CLI command `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` as shown [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#config-mode).

Comment: Check the webserver's error_log, too. In hosting environments, it is normally written to a subfolder in `~/`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Enabling Error reporting in magento2 is little tricky , as magento2 now comes with 3 different modes

1. Default
2. Developer
3. Production

Magento2 by default install in “default” mode and thats why you dont get the error log at the front-end of the site , that can a viewed at magento error log . You may check the complete details over here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

How to enable developer mode in Magento2

This is must have if you are a developer and building extension and template for magento2 , magento provide a command for this purpose . Login in to your linux terminal and under magento execute

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

and it will enable the developer mode under your magento instance for production mode you can set the mode to production or default .

still if you are experiencing in error reporting

> you can give a try by renaming local.xml.sample to local.xml under
>   pub/errors

Answer (score 41):

Add following code in index.php file :-

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Setting developer mode does not makes fatal errors display. In my case I saw white page. This one fixes :) Thanks.

Comment: for initial white-page errors (pre-magento / PHP) this does provide better results.

Comment: This is already contained in `app/bootstrap.php` as a commented code line. One may also remove the comment there…

Comment: First, check your `php.ini`. If error_reporting or display is turned off there, you should fix it there instead of in the `bootstrap.php`. Otherwise you end up displaying errors in production and maybe leaking sensible data.

Comment: There some latest blog available for the same https://www.codedecorator.com/blog/how-to-enable-error-log-in-magento2-4/

Answer (score 14):

There is a place for this. In `bootstrap.php`, there is:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Just uncomment that.

Answer (score 8):

1) **app/bootstrap.php**, there is:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Kindly uncomment that.

2) Run below commands

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: `php bin/magento cache:clean` is a subset of `php bin/magento cache:flush`, in other workds you only need run the `cache:flush`

Answer (score 3):

To check current mode use:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

Comment: Thats not the question

Comment: sometimes we should look at the issue a bit wider than it appears, this is also in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of editing `index.php` or `app/bootstrap.php` file, you can also edit the `.htaccess` file to enable PHP display errors settings.

Write the following lines of code at the end of the `.htaccess` file present in your Magento2 website's root directory:

```
## enable PHP's error display settings
php_value display_errors on
## set error display to E_ALL
php_value error_reporting -1
```

After that,

- Open terminal
- Go to your Magento's root directory

  ```
  cd /path/to/your/magento/root/folder
  ```
- Run the following command to enable developer mode:

  ```
  php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
  ```
- To check your current developer mode, you can run the command:

  ```
  php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Please Put the following code in index.php

```
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
   register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
   function fatal_handler() {
     $error = error_get_last();
     echo("<pre>");
     print_r($error);
   }
```